# Immer and a class derived from Map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immer.js

I am using `useImmerReducer` in my react app for the first time, but have run across a problem.

I am using a class derived from `Map`, which I call `Mappable`:

```
import { immerable } from "immer";

type KeyValueOf<T, K extends {}> = keyof T;

export default class Mappable<K, V> extends Map {
  [immerable] = true;

  constructor();
  constructor(entries: readonly (readonly [K, V])[]);
  constructor(entries: readonly V[], key: KeyValueOf<V, string>);

  constructor(
    entries?: readonly (readonly [K, V])[] | readonly V[],
    key?: keyof V
  ) {
    let superEntries: Map<V[keyof V], V> | readonly (readonly [K, V])[];

    if (key) {
      superEntries = new Map(
        (entries as readonly V[]).map((entry: V) => [entry[key], entry])
      );
    } else if (entries) {
      superEntries = entries as readonly (readonly [K, V])[];
    } else {
      superEntries = new Map();
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    super(superEntries);
  }

  map = <T>(predicate: (key: K, value: V) => T): Mappable<K, T> => {
    let map: Mappable<K, T> = new Mappable();

    super.forEach((value: V, key: K) => {
      map.set(key, predicate(key, value));
    });

    return map;
  };
}
```

My reducer state includes an instance of this `Mappable`:

```
export interface SelectorState {
  columns: SelectorColumnData[];
  checked: Mappable<ItemId, ItemCheckedStateTree>;
}
```

...but it seems when my reducer exits – or at some point at least, struggling to pinpoint where (I've even had `setTimeout`s trying to debug this) – my `Mappable` is cast back to a `Map` in the state, and so my `.map()` invocation on `Mappable` falls over.

Really struggling to pinpoint where this might be happening.

I have this function, the result of which is passed to a component as a prop:

```
export const columnCheckedState = (
  state: SelectorState,
  columnIndex: number
): Mappable<ItemId, CheckedState> => {
  console.log("columnCheckedState", state);
  return state.checked.map(
    (id, item: ItemCheckedStateTree) => item.checkedState
  );
};
```

Now, sometimes `state.checked` is a `Map`, and sometimes it is a `Mappable`. As I say, can't pinpoint where. I suspect it is happening when the new state is produced at the end of the reducer.

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure I'll be asked to produce a code sandbox or something, and I might struggle with that for various reasons; but my first port of call is to see if anyone knows off the top of their head what might be happening.

Failing that, code sandbox here we come...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems it's not possible

> Immer does not support exotic / engine native objects such as DOM Nodes or Buffers, nor is subclassing Map, Set or arrays supported and the immerable symbol can't be used on them.

From https://immerjs.github.io/immer/complex-objects/